# Is it possible to have icon in pyFLTK menubar?

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, fltk

How do I make these icons in pyFLTK?

[image: image showing icons]

My code:

```py
from fltk import *

def exitcb(widget,v):
    w.hide()

def demo1cb(widget,v):
    fl_message("this is the Test1 callback")
    
def demo2cb(widget,v):
    fl_message("this is the Test2 callback")

w = Fl_Window(600, 50, 300, 400, "Menus with icons")
w.begin()
menu=Fl_Menu_Bar(0,0,300,25)
menu.add("File/Exit",      FL_F + 5, exitcb, 0,0)
menu.add("File/Open/Test1",FL_F + 6, demo1cb,0,0)
menu.add("File/Open/Test2",FL_F + 7, demo2cb,0,0)
Fl_Check_Button(10, 30, 40, 20, 'GG')
w.end()
w.show()
Fl.run()
```

Comment: i wish to create a `pyFLTK` tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not supported out of the box. However,Albrecht Schlosser once created a way to do this in C++, you can find his approach using Fl_Multi_Label here: https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/examples/howto-menu-with-images.cxx
If you give me some time I will see whether I can get it working also in pyFltk.

Comment: oh thanks. take your time I wait you @Andreas

Comment: nice @Andreas am also wait you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this took a little bit longer than expected. The short is that this is not possible with the current version of pyFltk. However, if you are willing to wait a little bit longer, that is, until the release of pyFltk-1.3.6, then we will support this feature. There will again be a test file named "menu_label.py" that shows the usage of the feature. Basically, what you will have to do is the following:

```
def addItemToMenu(menu,                   # menu to add item to
          labeltext,              # label text
          shortcut,               # shortcut (e.g. FL_COMMAND+'a')
          cb,                     # callback to invoke
          userdata,               # userdata for callback
          pixmap,                 # image (if any) to add to item
          flags=0               # menu flags (e.g. FL_MENU_DIVIDER..)
          ):
  # Add a new menu item
  i = menu.add(labeltext, shortcut, cb, userdata, flags)
  item = menu.find_item(labeltext)
  item.add_multi_label(pixmap)
```

Of course, this has to be embedded in the overall code, for instance, like this:

```
def createMenuItems(menu):
    # Add items with LABELS AND IMAGES using Fl_Multi_Label..
    addItemToMenu(menu, "File/New",  FL_COMMAND | ord('n'), onMenu, "New",  L_document_pixmap)
    addItemToMenu(menu, "File/Open", FL_COMMAND | ord('o'), onMenu, "Open", L_folder_pixmap, FL_MENU_DIVIDER)
    addItemToMenu(menu, "File/Quit", FL_COMMAND | ord('q'), onFileQuit, "Quit", L_redx_pixmap)

    # Create menu bar items with JUST LABELS
    menu.add("Edit/Copy", FL_COMMAND | ord('c'), onMenu, "Copy")
    menu.add("Edit/Paste", FL_COMMAND | ord('v'), onMenu, "Paste")

    i = menu.add("Images/One", 0, onMenu, "One");
    item = menu.find_item("Images/One")
    l_img = L_document_pixmap.copy()
    item.image(L_document_pixmap.copy())

    i = menu.add("Images/Two", 0, onMenu, "Two")
    item = menu.find_item("Images/Two")
    item.image(L_folder_pixmap.copy())

    i = menu.add("Images/Three", 0, onMenu, "Three")
    item = menu.find_item("Images/Three")
    item.image(L_redx_pixmap.copy())enter code here
```

This is basically the example by Albrecht Schlosser, converted to Python.

At the moment, we are expecting a release of pyFltk-1.3.6 in about two weeks time.

Good luck

Andreas

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but we have now released the latest version of pyFltk, which covers the above problem. Please visit https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyfltk/ to obtain that release.